# Storing and retrieving copmosit objects in Java

Tags: java, hibernate, composition

I have more than 2 classes which have approximately 7 same fields and it will be like the following in java part:

```
public abstract class IBase {
   private String commonField1;
   private String commonField2;
   private String commonField3;
   private EMyType type; // type of the object: MY_TYPE_1 or MY_TYPE_2
   // ...

   // + constructor and getters/setters
}

public class BaseImpl1 extends IBase {
   private int base1specific1;
   private int base1specific2;
   // ...

   // + constructor and getters/setters
}

public class BaseImpl2 extends IBase {
   private int base2specific;
   private String base2specific2;
    // ...

   // + constructor and getters/setters
}
```

I have two questions:

1. what is the best way to reflect those 2 object within database?
2. how should I retrieve them via Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Using Morphia, you'd mark your interface with @Entity(someCollectionName).  Then when you're querying for those types, you have something like datastore.createQuery(BaseImpl1.class).filter("classname = ", BaseImpl1.class.getName()) to retrieve just that particular subclass.

Comment: thanks a lot! I will mark you answer as helpful, but it has been answered only for part of my question ...

Comment: iirc, hibernate would do something very similar though you might need an extra parameter or annotation to put the subclasses all in one table.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tackle question 3.  The others are very general questions.

In mongo you store things (documents) in collections.  There are no schemas or tables.  You could store both subtypes in the same collection and query over their common properties, or the subtype properties.  When deserializing them from the database you could work out how to deserialize them based on which set of properties they have.